# jboss vs tomcat administration

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I have a java with spring web app (war), I will not use any jee features that don't run on tomcat.
I already call and expose webservices, but I do it with bundled cxf.

Currently I am using tomcat7.

- Is Jboss better for administration than tomcat ?
- Does Jboss provide
  more statistics/metrics ? (tomcat provides almost none).
- Does jboss
  provide any resources (processor, memory, **number of open files**)
  usage monitoring or graphs ?
- Maybe instead tomcat and jboss You would recommend some other open source application server good for monitoring and administration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomact7 is still way to go in your case.
Web part of Jboss is exposed through tomcat anyway, so for one spring app it is definitely a huge overkill and learning curve to learn jboss and host it on jboss, jboss doesn't really add any additional resources in that case in the nutshell, if you had a webfarm of apps then that where jboss comes in handy, as it is easier to do clustering and administer resources within apps. 
Instead of using tomcat I would probably suggested to try and use heroku which is quite straight forward.

Hope this helps.